# Debug menu disabled in Netbeans 8.0.2 when using Wampserver 3.1.1 and preinstalled Xdebug

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, wamp, xdebug

I'm trying to debug a PHP project for class, and when I try to set a breakpoint in Netbeans, nothing happens. If I go to the Debug menu, everything's grayed out except Attach Debugger, Stack (though everything in that submenu is grayed), New Breakpoint, and New Watch. However, if I try to set a breakpoint through the Debug menu...nothing.

I have looked at (and tried) just about every solution on StackOverflow related to Netbeans, Xdebug, and WAMP. This includes changing the php.ini file, changing the configuration settings in the project in Netbeans, changing the Debugging options in the PHP area of the Netbeans options menu. I have even tried installing a second Xdebug, but still nothing. There was one question in the past with this issue, and the OP updated his Netbeans to a more recent version and that fixed the problem, but I have the latest version already.

I've also looked at the NetBeans site and forums, Wampserver site and forums, and general Google searches for this issue. I finally gave up and I'm turning to the StackOverflow collective intelligence.

My installations:

- Windows 10 64-bit
- Netbeans 8.0.2
- Wampserver 3.1.1
- PHP 5.6.18 (though I tried switching to PHP 7.0 and the problem persisted)
- My server configuration shows that Xdebug is installed, and phpinfo() also shows it.

My code in php.ini:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension ="C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.18/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.4.0rc2-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.profiler_enable = on
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="C:/wamp/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp 
xdebug.remote_host=localhost 
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```